# Searching a Pandas DataFrame in Python for Updates

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, performance, optimization

I created a sample of the code I am trying to implement. I have a Pandas DataFrame that contains three columns: 'Department', 'Ticket ID', and 'Update Number'. The goal is to:

- Search the data frame for rows that share 'Department' and 'Ticket ID'
- Compare 'Update Number' if there is a repeat 'Department' 'Ticket ID' pair
- Drop the index containing the lower 'Update Number'
- Reset the index count to avoid looping problems and clean the df for the next step in the code

The code that I wrote works, but I feel like there has to be a more efficient way to do this. I know how to deduplicate identical rows and this is implemented earlier in the code.

```
#import pandas
import pandas as pd

#create the sample DataFame
df = pd.DataFrame({'Department':['HR','DEV','HR'],'Ticket ID':['100', '100', '100'], 'Update Number':['1','1','2']})

print(df)

try:
    for base_index, base_entry in enumerate(df['Ticket ID']):
        base_update = df.loc[base_index ]['Update Number']
        base_dept = df.loc[base_index]['Department']
        
        for compare_index, compare_entry in enumerate(df['Ticket ID']):
            compare_update = df.loc[compare_index]['Update Number']
            compare_dept = df.loc[compare_index]['Department']
            
            if base_entry == compare_entry and base_dept == compare_dept:
                if int(compare_update) > int(base_update):
                    df.drop(base_index, inplace=True)
                    df = pd.concat([df], ignore_index=True)
except:
    pass
            
print('=====================================\n',df)
```

This is my current DataFrame:

```
  Department Ticket ID Update Number
0         HR       100             1
1        DEV       100             1
2         HR       100             2
```

AND desired output:

```
   Department Ticket ID Update Number
0        DEV       100             1
1         HR       100             2
```

I just want to do this more efficiently if possible.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this would be more efficient approach. Specifically, using `enumerate` and index-based lookups inside the loop might lead to unexpected results and errors.

Instead of manually iterating through the `DataFrame` and trying to modify it within the loop, you can use more efficient Pandas methods for this kind of data manipulation. Here's a modified version of your code that achieves the same goal using Pandas operations:

```
import pandas as pd

# Create the sample DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Department': ['HR', 'DEV', 'HR'],
    'Ticket ID': ['100', '100', '100'],
    'Update Number': ['1', '1', '2']
})

# Convert 'Update Number' to integer
df['Update Number'] = df['Update Number'].astype(int)

# Sort the DataFrame by 'Ticket ID', 'Department', and 'Update Number'
df = df.sort_values(by=['Ticket ID', 'Department', 'Update Number'], ascending=[True, True, False])

# Keep only the first occurrence of each combination of 'Ticket ID' and 'Department'
df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Ticket ID', 'Department'], keep='first')

print(df)
```

Output:

```
  Department Ticket ID  Update Number
1        DEV       100              1
2         HR       100              2
```

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you! Do have a more effective way to reset the index count or should I just keep 

`df = pd.concat([df], ignore_index=True)`

Comment: You can just keep it.